# Which strictly increasing functions $f(x,y)$ are linear when $x=0$ or $y=0$ or $x=y$?

Tags: calculus

Let $w_1, w_2 > 0$.

I am interested in differentiable functions $f \colon [0,1]^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ that satisfy the following conditions:

- $f(x,0) = w_1 \,x$ and $f(0,y) = w_2 \,y,$
- $f(x,1) = w_1 \, x + w_2$ and $f(1,y) = w_1 + w_2 \, y,$
- $f(x,x) = (w_1 + w_2) x$,
- $f$ has strictly positive partial derivatives: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} > 0$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} > 0$.

[image]

Clearly, $f(x, y) = w_1 \, x + w_2 \, y$ is a solution.
But are there other solutions (in closed form)? Maybe a function which is strictly concave on $(0,1)^2$?

Comment: What are $\displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial e_1}$ and $\displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial e_2}$ ?

Comment: Sorry, a typo. Should be correct now.

Comment: Kelenner, those must be the partial derivatives for the first and second argument, respectively.

Comment: ES, your second point should read f(1,y)=w1+w2y.

Comment: Ok. Let $g(x,y)=(x-y)xy(1-x)(1-y)$, $f(x,y)=w_1x+w_2y$, and put $h(x,y)=g(x,y)+f(x,y)$. Then $h$ satisfy your $3$ first conditions, and as $\displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=w_1$, and the continuous $\displaystyle \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$ is bounded on the compact set $[0,1]\times [0,1]$, then if $w_1$ is sufficiently large, we have $\displaystyle \frac{\partial h}{\partial x} >0$. The same for $\displaystyle \frac{\partial h}{\partial y}$ for $w_2$ large. Hence $h$ is a new solution, but only for $w_1$ and $w_2$ large..

Comment: I think you want $(0,1)^2$ instead of $[0,1]^2$ as $f$ would not be differentiable at $0,1$.

Comment: In fact, in my comment, take $cg(x,y)$ for $c$ small instead of $g(x,y)$ to have a solution with $w_1,w_2$ as given.

Comment: You are welcome.